# All available processors to Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v

My host has 4 cores and 8 logical processors (hyper-threading).

I'm going to run a single VM in Hyper-V and want it to use all processor power available.

How many virtual processors should I set?

Should it be equal to number of cores or logical processors?

Comment: I don't have rule of thumb, but my hunch does tell me I should just at most use the number of physical cores, so in the worst case the host is still left with some (practical) bottom line CPU resource. But if your host is practically unused most of the time (like, you only open a few docs on it because your boss requires you to use office / adobe reader on windows to do that), while you do heavy jobs most of the time on the VM (e.g software compilation), perhaps you should try the number of logical threads.

Comment: The problem is, it's kinda hard to keep Windows in the state of "unused". It's well known to do known or unknown background jobs all the time (well, I mean from time to time, I guess) that at least warms up you CPU, so...

Comment: Remember that if the host is underpowered and sluggish, so also will the VMs be sluggish. I added that to my answer so as to be very clear.

Comment: as mentioned, you shouldn't assign all CPU the VM.  Hyper-V CPU allocation is essentially sharing a slice of CPU processing power, however, the entire amount of CPU time needs to be free for the VM to use it, if the requested amount isn't currently available, the VM will have to wait until it becomes free, essentially reducing the VM's performance.  More CPU resources assigned to the VM doesn't automatically mean more speed/power to the VM.  You can also starve the host reducing overall performance.  Start with half your system resources and work from there, but always leave some for the host

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb for virtual machines is not more than half the host resources (multiple CPU and Memory).

Assigning more than half can very possibly cause the host to go sluggish for lack of resources. There is more flexibility with memory, depending on the needs of the host machine.

If your host is sluggish, so also will your virtual machines be sluggish.

Comment: My question was:
> ...want it to use all processor power available.

Comment: If you are trying to use all available CPU for the VM, that has a practical limit. As noted, do not assign more than half the host CPU and memory to guests.  This assumes multiple CPU.